# Live Sass compiler throws an error when processing the mixin

Tags: sass, mixins, scss-mixins

My problem: the live Sass compiler throws an error when processing the mixin:

> Compilation Error
> Error: 2 arguments required, but only 1 was passed.
> ╷
> 8 │ $fontSize: rem(14);
> ^^^^^^^

Here is the mixin itself, it converts px to rem.

```
@function rem($px) {
    $result: calc(($px / 16) * 1rem);
    @return $result;
}
```

Yesterday everything was fine, today this problem appeared, I don’t know where to look anymore.

Comment: Make sure you are using the maintained version of Live Sass Complier (the one by glenn2223, not ritwickdey).

Comment: Yes, the version is up-to-date from glenn2223. I didn’t make any changes to the settings, it just stopped working.

Comment: In what a problem and did not find. But renaming the mixin helped. rem() error. Renamed to remmm(), everything is fine.

Comment: I think you can write an answer for your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming the mixin helped. rem() error. Renamed to remmm(), everything is fine. rem() already exists in SASS and its name is not suitable for a custom mixin.

```
@function remmm($px)
```

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this in the SASS docs, but I can't find where... So, actually the [`rem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/rem) function exists in CSS, it's not specific to SASS.